# react client side rendering with django

Tags: django, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-server

I am integrating reactjs with my django, I have done setup and even able to render page from server too, but in client side when it comes to rendering and event handling and attaching, I am getting error "Uncaught ReferenceError: MainContainer is not defined".
I am totally lost here, please help me.

[image: error in index.html]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/src/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/src/css/style.less"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
                  // var INITIAL_DATA = JSON.parse('{{ serialized_value|safe }}')
                    var INITIAL_DATA = {{ serialized_value|safe }}
        </script>
        <div id="app">{{ rendered|safe }}</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/build/index_webpack.js"></script>
        <script>
            // ReactDOM.render(React.createFactory(MainContainer)({isOpen: false, props: {'freeShipping': free_shipping_message_new,'navigationBar': [loose_leaf_content]}}), document.getElementById('app'));
            ReactDOM.render(MainContainer({isOpen: false, props: {'freeShipping': free_shipping_message_new,'navigationBar': [loose_leaf_content]}}), document.getElementById('app'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `MainContainer` is presumably a React component. Is the component declared or imported in `index_webpack.js`? If so, is that file being correctly loaded? If not, you'll need to import the component into the window somehow.

Comment: I checked in my index_webpack.js, component is imported there, but somehow, Idk why i am getting error!, but if it not working for me, can you tell me how to import in window?

Comment: Normally I would have the whole javascript (including your `ReactDOM.render` line) in the webpack bundle. That way you know it's all in one place. Is the `index_webpack.js` being loaded successfully?

Comment: @ChidG, I got this, I created another app.jsx file and I attached all my components with window object and mentioned this file in entry point of webpack.config.js, and guess what! it is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better using [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) to help you integrate your webpack bundles into django templates. For us, it took a lot of the pains away from setting webpack up alongside django. Now we don't have to think about webpack at all, it just sits there and automatically builds all of our apps and we can just integrate the bundles into our templates with

```
{% render_bundle 'react_app' %}
```